# Certificate for TCPDF

Tags: php, certificate, tcpdf

I would like to generate a certificate(self-signed at the moment) for an encrypted PDF on the server. What is interesting to me is the workflow on how to to that with TCPDF.

**What I did:**

1) Generate keys:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365000 -newkey rsa:1024 
openssl pkcs12 -export -in tcpdf.crt -out tcpdf.p12
```

2) Then generate the PDF with the `.crt` - file

3) Then I started acrobat reader and installed the certificate (`tcpdf.p12`). I used Document->security settings -> digital id

4) I could import the security settings but still can't open the PDF. Don't know if I am doing it right? What happens that acrobat reader 9.5.4 opens a dialog with input of a password. I give in the password and an error appears -> unknown error -> CRecipientList-218

5) Code I used (basically the same)

```
$certificate = 'file://../tcpdf.crt';
$info = array(
'Name' => 'TCPDF',
'Location' => 'Office',
'Reason' => 'Testing TCPDF',
'ContactInfo' => 'http://www.tcpdf.org',
);
$pdf->setSignature($certificate, $certificate, 'tcpdfdemo', '', 2, $info);
$pdf->SetProtection($permissions=array('print', 'copy'), $user_pass='', owner_pass=null, $mode=1, $pubkeys=array(array('c' => 'file://../tcpdf.crt', 'p' => array('print'))));
```

I combined the following examples:

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_052.phps

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_016.phps

P.S.: I know its a very practical example. Just thought its easier to understand the steps I am doing.

**Questions:**

1. Is the workflow in general right on how(!) to approach certificates for a PDF with encryption?
2. When I generate the `.p12` file I have to give in a password for that file which I used later on when imported the certificate into acrobat. I'm asking because I have also the possibility "on generation" to give the password.
3. If the workflow is right...how do I fix the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to contact tcpdf guys instead?

Comment: I did, but there is no answer so far on sourceforge.

Answer (score 4):

The approach is basically correct - but you may have missed some detail in it.

I have been using the certificate in `*.crt` format without the passphrase (including private and public key) and it works fine.

Also note, that you must have installed OpenSSL extension in PHP.

See the comments for method `TCPDF::setSignature()` by Nicola Asuni:

```
* To create self-signed signature: openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout tcpdf.crt -out tcpdf.crt
* To export crt to p12: openssl pkcs12 -export -in tcpdf.crt -out tcpdf.p12
* To convert pfx certificate to pem: openssl pkcs12 -in tcpdf.pfx -out tcpdf.crt -nodes
```

You dont need to install any certificate into Acrobat Reader - generated PDF documents signed with self-signed certificates simply show up as untrusted, but still they can normally open.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you also took a look at the comments ;)
there is a mini how to setup the pdf using provided file

especially:

```
// To open the document you need to install the private key (tcpdf.p12) on the Acrobat Reader. The password is: 1234
```

however, you need to provide setProtection with existing key:

```
'c' => 'file://../tcpdf.crt'
```

the path you given is just showing where you need to give the path, but the path itself need to be changed

Summary: please read again the comments in the example 016 file, they WILL help to get it working the way you need

Comment: Of course I changed the path. Every example works on its own but not together.