# PHP create digitally signed certificat for PDF signing

Tags: php, pdf, certificate

I want to create a digitally signed PDF's in my system, and I want to create a unique certificate per user.

I had found how to create a domain certificate using PHP, but I'll be happy to find a way to create PDF digitally sign certificate.

**I know how to sign the PDF, I am looking for a way to create a certificate using PHP**
Thank

Comment: How do you suppose to sign the pdf with the given certificate...and what kind of certificate are you looking for(.pem, .cert, etc)

Comment: I am looking for .crt file, and I am going to sign it with tcpdf

Comment: I am looking for a PHP based solution, but if there isn't any I can use Linux (Debian) based solution

Comment: Like this maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126274/certificate-for-tcpdf

Comment: Thanks, but are you familiar with a PHP based solution for that, without running external resource?

Comment: Nope....i try to do something like that once, but finally create a java web applet to do the work(i have to work with aladin eToken based cert)